# Sublime Text: How to expand one level at a time? (Alt + Click functionality)

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, tooling

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to fold and unfold code blocks one level at a time by using the standardized Alt+Click functionality that Finder, Chrome, and many apps use when clicking a caret or chevron at the side.

After collapsing a code block, unfolding also unfolds all children and I have to re-collapse back to the right indentation, which is slightly annoying..

Does any Sublime plugin include this functionality or is it a hidden setting? Which Sublime plugin(s), if any?